# Krull dimension of a $\mathbb Q$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

> I'm trying to find the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(X^{2}-Y,Z^{2})$.

My professor said that I have to consider that $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(X^{2}-Y,Z^{2})$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, but I don't know how to proceed.

I think I have to find a transcendence basis for this $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, but I don't how to make the computations.

Any help will be welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Another approach: $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(X^{2}-Y,Z^{2})\simeq\mathbb{Q}[X,Z]/(Z^{2})=(\mathbb{Q}[X])[Z]/(Z^2)$, and the last ring is integral over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(X^{2}-Y,Z^{2})=\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ with $x^2=y$ and $z^2=0$. Thus you have an integral extension $\mathbb Q[y]\subset\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$. Now try to show that $\mathbb Q[y]\simeq\mathbb Q[Y]$ (that is, $y$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$) and find out the Krull dimension.

Comment: Thank you @YACP!. My problem now is how I show that y is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ and how I see that the extension $\mathbb{Q[y]\subset\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$? Thank you so much for your help, and sorry my silly question

Comment: I wanted to say that I don't understand why the extension is integral, how can I prove this? And just to make sure that I understand your last inequality is impossible to $f \neq 0$ because $f$ is a polynomial in Y over $\mathbb{Q}$? Thank you so much!

Comment: oh I Understand it now! I have to consider the polynomial $phi(T) = T^{2}$ and $phi(T) = T^{2}-y$ and the integrality is proved. Thank you! Your help was very important!